# Как тестировать приложение ASP.NET WebForms?

Tags: asp.net-webforms

Как правильно подойти к тестированию приложения без существенного усложнения кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду тест на правильно работающую навигацию, то почитайте статью: [Unit Testing in the Navigation for ASP.NET Web Forms Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj133824.aspx).

Если хотите потестировать исполняемый код, то вам сюда: [Testing ASP.NET webforms applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301705).